# xsd:double restriction to six decimal place

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have a case where I want to put restriction on XSd:double element. The precision should be 6 decimal place and should throw an exception if more than 6 decimal places entered or should be appended with 0's if less than 6 decimal places entered.

Is it possible to achieve through xsd restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather strange requirement: if decimal places matter so much, I would expect you to be using `xs:decimal` rather than `xs:double`, in which case you can use the `totalDigits` and `fractionDigits` facets to restrict the value.

If you want to restrict xs:double in this way, you will have to do it using a pattern (regular expression).

Comment: I will be able to place restriction through the pattern on double but is there a way to append 0's at the end if less than 6 decimal places are entered?

Comment: A schema doesn't give you any opportunity to change the lexical representation of the value from what is written, other than whitespace normalization. The schema can only say whether the value is valid. (Unless you use the Saxon schema processor and the saxon:preprocess extension facet...)